# Can't center <UL>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dynamic UL, and I need it to be centered in my page.

***Here is my HTML:***

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><div class="tabquad">First</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">One</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Two</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Three</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div class="tabquad">Second</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">One</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Two</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Three</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Four</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Five</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div class="tabquad">Third</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">One</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Two</div></a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="#"><div class="tabquad">Three</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***My CSS:***

```
.tabquad{
    color:white;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-color:rgb(82,115,154);
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    top:25px;
    background-color:rgb(0,56,130);
}
.tabquad:hover{
    background-color:rgb(49,87,132);
    cursor: hand;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 15em;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 15em;
}
#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15em;
    left: -999em;
}

.item{
    color:#0E4063;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

***My JS:***

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
```

How do I center the whole thing?

Here you can find a test on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6A7GM/2/)

EDIT: I need 3 columns, all centered in my page.

Comment: which ul your talking about?

Comment: i need every ul to be centered, as 3 columns. actually the whole thing is centered on the left side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this after your first `#nav` definition:

```
#nav {
    width: 45em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/ZGLtn/2/

Comment: Ehm... Everything is in coulmn, and it's not what I'm looking for. I will add more details to my question, sorry.

Comment: so, the principle is the same. fixed width + auto margin. I updated my fiddle for 45em width.

Comment: I still see "First", "Second" and "Third" not horizontally, but vertically.

Comment: the jsfiddle url changed, make sure you are on the new one.

Comment: Ok dude, sorry, you won ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to give fixed width to the ul then add a outer `div` to `ul` and give `text-align:center` to the outer div

**HTML**

```
     <div class="wrap">
         ul goes here
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{text-align:center}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6A7GM/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use marginLeft and marginRight 'auto' with a width for the UL tag so that the left and right margin is automatically taken. For instance,

```
ul{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* This center aligns the ul horizontally */
}
```

Comment: this will mess up the child ULs.

Comment: My bad. I just wrote that for an instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    width: 45em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
```